# C Check duplicate string entries

Tags: c, duplicates, c-strings

I need to check if in my file there are duplicates entries, in C.

Sample file:

```
/proc/proc1 1000
/proc/proc2 2000
/proc/proc1 3000
```

I need to solve like this:

```
/proc/proc1 1000 3000
/proc/proc2 2000
```

The path (/proc/proc*) can include spaces likes: /proc/proc hello/foo

[Here](http://pastebin.com/AKTy2PQA) I wrote something to handle /proc/ and their pids, but now I'm stuck on this problem..

Comment: Why don't you write a shell script? Much better suited for such tasks, then C.

Comment: I know, but I must solve it with C :( It's a OS exercise.

I can't figure out why all those -1. I'm not asking to develop a Kernel, but some hints to solve that kind of problem. We're not all pros :/

Comment: Split the entries into key `"/proc/proc hello/foo"` and value. Make a map `key -> set of values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char str[]= "/proc/proc hello/foo 4000";
    char path[256];
    char pid[10];
    char *p;

    p=strrchr(str, ' ');
    strcpy(pid, p+1);
    *p='\0';
    strcpy(path, str);
    printf("%s\n", path);// /proc/proc hello/foo
    printf("%s\n", pid);// 4000

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! [HERE](http://pastebin.com/vbmFA7yW) the complete solution :) It cost me 8 reputation points :'(

Comment: It's useful to someone after all :)