# Comparing two string tokens in an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtok

I am confused on how to do this properly. Lets say I have an array of characters in C:

```
char str[200];
```

and i fill it something like:

```
"Hello, this is an an is hello example!"
```

Now I break up my array with `strtok` and insert these tokens into a separate character array:

```
char *pch;
char *tokens[200][20];
const char *s = " ,.!"
int i;

for (pch = strtok(str, s), i = 0; p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, s), i++) {
    tokens[i][20] = pch;
}
```

My string is now:

```
Hello
this
is
an
an
is
hello
example
```

Now I want to compare and find the duplicate strings, but i'm not sure how to proceed.

I tried using `strstr`:

```
if (strstr(str, pch) == NULL)
```

but it would only output my sentence like this

```
this
is
an
an
is
hello
```

I'm not sure how to implement something to check every string in the array for duplicates.

The final output should be:

```
 Hello
 this
 is
 an
 example
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C Check duplicate string entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638386/c-check-duplicate-string-entries)

Comment: `tokens[anything][20]` is out of bounds.

Comment: `strtok` returns pointers into the original string, which it modifies. You need an array of pointers to `char`. I think you have one dimension too many.

Comment: You need to use `strcmp` after correcting the errors. Try `man strcmp` in a unix shell

Comment: Please don't put the entire implementation in to the `for` loop statement, it makes it just as hard to read as an unformatted one-liner. It is more usual to implement `strtok` in a `while` loop.

Comment: Why are you using a 2-D array for the token pointers? You are not copying the token's text, only its pointer. When you advance to the *next* string, those pointers will become invalid, so I would expect to see the token text being copied to your 2D array, not its pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't find that too difficult to read, so I'm not exactly sure why you're complaining. This is no `if ((x & (x + 1)) == 0)`, or it's non-bracketed, guaranteed-to-compile alternative `if (x & -~x ? 0 : 1)`...

Comment: @Ben **I don't think that duplicate is appropriate**, but I do think this question should be closed for a different reason... :)